# excel if statement having a range in a single cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

At the moment I am working on using on implementing nested if statement in excel for a project. It involves calculating the tax of employees using a tax table and would like to know if it possible for a logical test to distinguish a range within a singular cell i.e $0-$18,000

Comment: so if I understand this right, you have let's say a cell `A1` that has the content `"$0-$18,000"` and you would like to test a given value `X` if it is in the range of $0 to $18,00. Am I right with this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are open to using VLOOKUP, you can create a table showing the range and the associated value with it and use vlookup with the last argument being TRUE (approximate match) to get the value.

[image]

This is the output:

```
 1.00        10%
 100,000.00  30%
 40,000.00   25%
 17,999.00   10%
 18,000.00   10%
 18,001.00   15%
```

Answer (score 0):

Try nested `IF` and `AND` formulas in combination. For example, there are three ranges: `0-18 000, 18 000- 23 000, 23 000<`, then use this:

`=IF(AND(A1>=0, A1<=18000),"range 1",IF(AND(A1>18000, A1<=23000),"range 2","range 3"))`